# react-router v4 - MatchWhenAuthorized example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In the example here - https://react-router.now.sh/auth-workflow - the "login" route still matches after you've logged in (by typing the address in the address bar or something similar).

Is there a more elegant solution to this problem apart from creating something like MatchWithAuthTestBefore, which would take a pair of components to render - one when authorized and one when not?

Answer (score 0):

Since RRv4 is all about components, the solution is to handle this in a component. Essentially the opposite of the `<MatchWhenAuthorized>` component listed in the example where you redirect if the user is logged in.

```
const MatchWhenUnauthorized = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Match {...rest} render={props => (
    !fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
      <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/' }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)
```

This is similar to what you would do with a normal routing/view configuration (match `/login` and in the `login` view you would redirect if the user is already authenticated).